# Writing an .htaccess to point to a public directory in a subdomain of my shared host

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, zend-framework2

I've created a subdomain on my shared hosting to run an Zend Framework 2 application. I developed the application at home where it sits within a virtual host then uploaded it to the subdomain's root directory. The root directory can be found at:

public_html/mysubdomain/

I want to write an .htaccess file that can direct all requests to the public directory with mod_rewrite. My .htaccess is as follows

```
<VirtualHost mysubdomain.mydomain.com:80>
  ServerName mysubdomain.mydomain.com
  DocumentRoot /home/myusername/public_html/mysubdomainfolder/public

  RewriteEngine off

  <Location />
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [NC,L]
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

.. but I get a server error (500). Basically when the user enters mysubdomain.mydomain.com/users/login into the browser, it will re write the URL to the public directory and the index.php file will handle things from there.

Can anyone offer any advice on what I've done wrong here? (or how I should be doing it) I took this from the ZF2 htaccess page and modified it to my domain. I can't see what's missing from it (although obviously something :)

Thanks

Comment: For starters, your two rules test for the same condition, so your second rule will never fire. Also, not understanding where you want to rewrite to. Please give a specific example, eg this url must redirect to this path

Comment: Specifically I have a subdomain at budgetz.rtyn.biz. This points to a folder /public_html/budgetz/ and my htaccess file lives there too. So when someone enters budgetz.rtyn.biz it will point to this folder. I want anyone who enters this subdomain as well as perhaps a query string (e.g. budgetz.rtyn.biz/users/signup) to be pointed to .../public_html/budgetz/public/ through a rewrite. The index file in the folder will handle which controller/ action to fire from the URL. A typically front controller pattern (I think :)